# weblogic upgrade servlet encode url issue

Tags: weblogic, servlet-3.0

we upgraded the weblogic domain from 10.0 to 12c. After upgrading we keep on getting the error, while opening the home page.Other web-service and everything else works fine.

```
*java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3035)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:607)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.encodeURL(ServletResponseImpl.java:655)
    at com.adecco.adeccoClub.presentation.View.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.adecco.adeccoClub.presentation.ViewAdeccoClub.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.webmacro.servlet.WMServlet.doRequest(WMServlet.java:251)
    at org.webmacro.servlet.WMServlet.doGet(WMServlet.java:191)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:590)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:273)
    at com.adecco.adeccoClub.presentation.command.AdeccoClubMainServlet.forward(Unknown Source)
    at com.adecco.adeccoClub.presentation.command.AdeccoClubMainServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at com.adecco.adeccoClub.presentation.command.AdeccoClubMainServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While upgrading the domain, re-config domain wiped out the 
**-Dbase.url=eorder** [from startWeblogic.cmd], which was the URL it was encoding.